# The app crash when cannot find the column on SQLite Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite

im learning about SQLite on Android Studio. Testing several times a created several tables on SQLite and now im trying validating a column and the tool "run" (that shows all process running back) and it shows a next error and then the app just crash:

`E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column...`

I think is a error when i failed creating a table and now the code is trying reading a column on different table, i read about just unstalling a reinstalling the app on the emulator will fix the error, but it still appearing and crashing my app.

Sorry if this its too much obviously but im starting on this, thank you.

*The code of the class where is the SQLite Data Base*
Here is the name of the columns of the actual table

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DataBase) {
        DataBase.execSQL("create table datos(nombre text primary key, contraseña text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

I put just the class where the code is trying find the columns, i omitted the class where i registered data on the table, but ill put a image of the table.

```
 public void Iniciar(View view) {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "Registro", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BD1 = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String name = nombre.getText().toString();
        String pass = contra.getText().toString();

        if (!name.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()) {
            Cursor fila = BD1.rawQuery("select contraseña from datos where nombre =" + name, null);
            if (fila.getString(1).equals(name) && fila.getString(2).equals(pass)) {

                BD1.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se encontró el nombre de usuario o contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No puede quedar ningún campo vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The full error

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: David in "select contraseña from datos where nombre =David"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.iniciosesin2, PID: 19037
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: David (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select contraseña from datos where nombre =David
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
        at com.example.iniciosesin2.Inicio.Iniciar(Inicio.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19037 SIG: 9
```

Following the new statements

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: David in "select * from datos where nombre =David"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.iniciosesin2, PID: 24619
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: David (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from datos where nombre =David
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
        at com.example.iniciosesin2.Inicio.Iniciar(Inicio.java:38)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24619 SIG: 9
```

When i changed the version (DataBase of SQLite) it just crash at the first activity

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.iniciosesin2, PID: 25429
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:540)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:414)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
        at com.example.iniciosesin2.MainActivity.Registrarse(MainActivity.java:34)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25429 SIG: 9
```

And the image:

[The table with the name registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG3et.png)

Comment: Can you please post your full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Yes sorry, i edited the post

Comment: Hi,you cant declare a text as primary key you must use integer type for primary key and also make sure that your culomn names are the same in creating table and execting a query.

Comment: Once you get the cursor `fila` you should check whether the `fila.getCount>0` and proceed further. May be there is no data available. Could you check at your end by adding the code.

Comment: Hi Afshin thanks for your answer. Yes, when i started the app i put an Int for the first column, after i change it for try fix it but doesnt works. Now i changed again and the error persist.

At the second point, yes, im sure that are the same names on the table and the query.

Comment: @akhilnair I never used it before, but looks like good idea.
That code will check if Cursor it not empty?

Comment: @Cloudnine Ya it would.

Comment: Isn't nombre your primary key and so of type int? why are you looking for the name in that column?

Comment: @akhilnair I tried using the method "return" and it shows 0, it means the cursor its trying find a empty table, but as shows on the image, the table isnt empty. :(

Comment: @MehranBehbahani Hi, thanks for your comment. Im creating a register and login, each one on diferent activity, i register the name and the password and then try query the table to find the name registered, but the error shows it like " Cant find the column"

Comment: try to change the version

Comment: @HussainAbbas i did it, but now the crash is on the first activity (registration) I can't even register in the database, when it just crashes

Comment: ca you show me the first activity crash?

Comment: @HussainAbbas Ready, i update the post

Comment: @Cloudnine change your database version to 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. delete the database file already created on the emulator using `Device File Explorer`.

then use the following statement to create your table:

```
DataBase.execSQL("create table if not exists datos(id integer primary key autoincrement, nombre text,  contraseña text)");
```

and then when you want to query, use this:

```
Cursor fila = BD1.rawQuery("select * from datos where nombre = '"+name+"'", null);

fila.moveToNext()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im searching for all files inside the emulator, speciffically ond data/data, but i cant find the location database.

Comment: it should be in `data/data/your_package_name/databases`

Comment: Yes i got it, sorry.
Now, i tried it, delete my database and change the statements but the app still crashing where i execute that method

Comment: at which line? and share the crash report please. can you?

Comment: When i add a colomn with id, the names can repeat and that doesnt works for a login ¿or am i wrong?

Comment: That is not a problem. to solve that,  when you wanna save new password, in your edit statement you search for the name and edit that record.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks about the new method. I update the post, the error its too similar.

Comment: I think you need to use single quotation marks. just added it to my answer. try it again please. it means `David` should actually be` `David` `.

Comment: Hey, it works! Nice!
¿Can you explain what changes exactly, what its the difference putting that single quotation marks?

I did a database following my method and its work, but this time i try it but just work with your method

Comment: I'm glad I could help. it worked because the statement is supposed to be this `"select * from datos where nombre = 'David' "`. because `David` is a string value and when you wanna define a string value within another string value, you need to use single quotations.